# Spotify App Preview API Access model.player properties

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I've been playing around with the latest spotify preview api but I'm having issues accessing the player properties.
Im trying to get the current track playing. This is a my test snippet below.

```
require([
   '$api/models',
   '$api/search#Search',
   '$views/image#Image'
], function(models,s, Image) {
      'use strict';
       console.log(models.player.track)
});
```

however I get undefined in the console.log
It seen that I can only access the methods. Please have a look at the link for reference
http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/api-models-player.html

Answer (score 2):

Found It

So before you can access the player properties you must call the load method

```
require([
   '$api/models',
   '$api/search#Search',
   '$views/image#Image'
], function(models,s, Image) {
     'use strict';

     models.player.load('track').done(function(prop) {
           console.log(prop.track.name);
      });

});
```